# Excel - Return value of cell matching criteria and the max value of row containing matched criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I apologize for the poor wording of the title but it was the best I could do with the limited amount of characters.

On a side note, Excel is by far my weakest skill. I am a front-end developer developing a cloud-based application so unfortunately I am forced to work with CSVs here. Anyways...

I have a 40k+ line excel sheet with some basic political information(name, ... , contribution, and quarter for said contribution). I would like to create a formula that: matches the individual's name in all the lines(there are duplicates of the name but not of the other information), find the max value of another column after passing the first criteria, and then return the adjacent cell if the value is the maximum for the person being searched for. I provided several lines of the excel as a sample.

[image: SAMPLE DATA WITH EXPECTED RESULTS]

I'm sure I am completely looking over a simple formula for this. My brain is wired to be thinking in a loop (which I wish I could do) but any constructive help is appreciated. I am still very new to using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

In `Q2`:

`=LOOKUP(1,0/FREQUENCY(0,1/(1+(M$2:M$7=M2)*N$2:N$7)),O$2:O$7)`

Copy down as required.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This array formula will do:

```
{=OFFSET(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(MAX(IF(A:A=A2,B:B,"")),B:B,FALSE)),0,2)}
```

Make sure to confirm equation with  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  +  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> . The equal should be enclosed in `{}` brackets when if entered correctly.

[image]

Comment: You will just need to adjust the column's to match your setup.

Comment: So i have read about arrays in Excel and understand the idea behind them, but i cannot get mine to confirm and do the calculations. When i input it without the brackets just as a formula, it is only outputting the largest Amount's adjacent cell value.

Comment: Did you try to enter using ctrl shift enter

Comment: You may have a typo. The values from my screenshot are from the above formula